# Azure Table Storage QueryAll(), ImproveThroughput

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I have some data (approximatly 5 Mio of items in 1500 tables, 10GB) in azure tables. The entities can be large and contain some serialized binary data in the protobuf format.

I have to process all of them and transform it to another structure. This processing is not thread safe. I also process some data from a mongodb replica set using the same code (the mongodb is hosted in another datacenter).

For debugging purposes I log the throughput and realized that it is very low. With mongodb I have a throughput of 5000 items / sec, with azure table storage only 30 items per second.

To improve the performance I try to use TPL dataflow, but it doesnt help:

```
public async Task QueryAllAsync(Action<StoredConnectionSetModel> handler)
{
    List<CloudTable> tables = await QueryAllTablesAsync(companies, minDate);

    ActionBlock<StoredConnectionSetModel> handlerBlock = new ActionBlock<StoredConnectionSetModel>(handler, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });

    ActionBlock<CloudTable> downloaderBlock = new ActionBlock<CloudTable>(x => QueryTableAsync(x, s => handlerBlock.Post(s), completed), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 });

    foreach (CloudTable table in tables)
    {
        downloaderBlock.Post(table);
    }
}

private static async Task QueryTableAsync(CloudTable table, Action<StoredConnectionSetModel> handler)
{
    TableQuery<AzureTableEntity<StoredConnectionSetModel>> query = new TableQuery<AzureTableEntity<StoredConnectionSetModel>>();

    TableContinuationToken token = null;
    do
    {
        TableQuerySegment<AzureTableEntity<StoredConnectionSetModel>> segment = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<AzureTableEntity<StoredConnectionSetModel>>(query, token);

        foreach (var entity in segment.Results)
        {
            handler(entity.Entity);
        }

        token = segment.ContinuationToken;
    }
    while (token != null)
}
```

I run the batch process on my local machine (with 100mbit connection) and in azure (as worker role) and it is very strange, that the throughput on my machine is higher (100 items / sec) than on azure. I reach my max capacity of the internet connection locally but the worker role should not have this 100mbit limitation I hope.

How can I increase the throughput? I have no ideas what is going wrong here.

---

EDIT: I realized that I was wrong with the 30items per second. It is often higher (100/sec), depending on the size of the items I guess. According to the documentation (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#subheading10) there is a limit:

The scalability limit for accessing tables is up to 20,000 entities (1KB each) per second for an account. This are only 19MB / sec, not so impressive, if you keep in mind, that there are also normal requests from the production system). Probably I test it to use multiple accounts.

---

EDIT #2: I made two single tests, starting with a list of 500 keys [1...500] (Pseudo Code)

Test#1 Old approach (TABLE 1)

```
foreach (key1 in keys)
    foreach (key2 in keys)
        insert new Entity { paritionkey = key1, rowKey = key2 }
```

Test#2 New approach (TABLE 2)

```
numpartitions = 100
foreach (key1 in keys)
    foreach (key2 in keys)
        insert new Entity { paritionkey = (key1 + key2).GetHashCode() % numParitions, rowKey = key1 + key2 }
```

Each entity gets another property with 10KB of random text data.

Then I made the query tests, in the first case I just query all entities from Table 1 in one thread (sequential)

In the next test I create on task for each partitionkey and query all entities from Table 2 (parallel). I know that the test is no that good, because in my production environment I have a lot more partitions than only 500 per table, but it doesnt matter. At least the second attempt should perform well.

It makes no difference. My max throughput is 600 entities/sec, varying from 200 to 400 the most of the time. The documentation says that I can query 20.000 entities / sec (with 1 KB each), so I should get at least 1500 or so in average, I think. I tested it on a machine with 500MBit internet connection and I only reached about 30mbit, so this should not be the problem.

Comment: did you checked - Performance and storage scalability checklist- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/ If not please have a look

Comment: "To improve the performance I try to use TPL dataflow, but it doesnt help" This tells me you have no idea *why* this is slow and you have tried a random change to make it go faster. Not a good way to go. Find out why this is slow. Is the network maxed out locally? Is the CPU 100% busy (even on one core)?

Comment: @usr I think this is not true. As i mentioned above the network is maxed out locally, the cpu is at 20% (on all cores), so it seems to be the problem to get the data fast enough. The import process from mongodb shows that there is a lof of space to increase the throughput and make the cpu busy. I use data flow to make multiple requests in parallel and to synchronize the operations for the processing of the data.

Comment: How is the ratio of count(partitionkey)/count(rowkey)? Scans across partitions are very slow. So ideally you want to parallelize the calls for each partition.

Comment: I dont know exactly. We get data from a partner. Each data set is identified by 2 keys and a date. We have one table per date and use one key as row and one key as partitionkey. They have about 60.000 different keys, so there might be a lot of partitions. Typically we only need one entity (or data set) from the table and query it by date and keys.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I think you might be right, I might have to much partitions keys. This is not a problem when I read or update a single entry but might be problematic when doing the queries. Perhaps it is a better idea to calculate the partition key based on both keys (for example hashCode(key1 + key2) % 100 or so.

Comment: Yep, cryptographic hashes like SHA-256 mod X works also pretty well to shard across partitions.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Made a simple test (described above) but doesnt help.

Comment: Can you post the code with some artificial data generator? I'd like to reproduce.

Comment: Hello Thomas, here you find the link to the test application. It contains the code to generate the data and to query it.

https://drive.google.com/a/busliniensuche.de/file/d/0BzSqT6X48kYSU0FqeGhOY0R0QXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @ThomasJungblut Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a notification on Saturday. Will take a deeper look.

Comment: Confirming the ~450k/sec on the naive key1/key2 layout. But my bandwidth is maxed out, so that's where the bottleneck is- at least for me ;)

Comment: 600 qps for the other. I actually never seen tablestore do more.

Comment: `20,000 entities (1KB each) per second ` is what we call TPS (transactions per second), that is your qouta before you're getting throttled. This is not the read-speed from a table.

Comment: This documentation says: 2000 entities per partition and max 20.000 per account. So there is no chance to get near the limit? here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249410.aspx

Comment: `(assuming 1KB object size)` which is a very nice workload for tablestore ;)

Comment: I know, but my size is only 20kb +/-, so there is still some space left to 1000 entities / per second ;)

Comment: Your best bet here is indeed sharding over multiple accounts.

Comment: Yes, started with this strategy, making one account per month, lets see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75252/discussion-between-sebastianstehle-and-thomas-jungblut).

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out the [Table Storage Design Guide](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/). Hope this helps.